# How to make the receiver e-mail dynamic in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, email

I have a e-mail controller which handles the e-mail. Now, I want to read the receivers mail from the database.

This is my code

```
//Send email
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->helper('email');

        $this->email->set_mailtype("html");

        $FLnames = $this->input->post('firstname')." ".$this->input->post('lastname');

        $this->email->from($this->input->post('email'), $FLnames);
        $this->email->to('myemail@email.com'); //<--------  I want this to be retrieved from the databse
        $this->email->subject('Subject');
```

I am a little new to CodeIgniter so any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html), this is how you can e-mail multiple recipients:

```
$list = array('one@example.com', 'two@example.com', 'three@example.com');
$this->email->to($list);
```

Now to get $list from the DB you can use [Codeigniter's Active Record Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html), like this:

```
$this->db->select('email_field');
$list = $this->db->get('your_table')->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table of users with the following columns:

user_id, email

Create a function to get the email from the db:

```
function get_user_email($user_id) {

$this->db->select('email');
$this->db->where('user_id', $user_id); 
$query = $this->db->get("users"); 
$row = $query->row;
return $row->email

}
```

In your code, change this:

```
$this->email->to('myemail@email.com');
```

To this:
    $sent_to_email = get_user_email();
    $this->email->to($sent_to_email);

Hope this helps